# Flood of Warmup Requests

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Since today, I'm experiencing issues with floods of warmup requests that happen at what appear to be random times.

Usually my app runs on 1 or 2 instances, but today it regularly reached 40 instances. Those instances are all short-lived, since they only serve one request because there was no change in web traffic or usage.

Obviously this has severely impacted my budget, so I want to figure out what's happening.

I have one idle instance to avoid cold requests throughout the day. I have now disabled that and it has solved the problem (which I believe is obvious, because this simply disabled the warmup requests if understand the manual correctly)

Of course, this also impacts the user experience.

So my questions:

- What triggers warmup requests?
- What triggers 40 warmup requests at a time? And how do I debug this?
- Can I make it so that the algorithm that starts instances doesn't "overreact"?

I've also [filed a production issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9738&q=Type=Production%20reporter%3ame&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log), but from what I read, I won't be receiving any feedback there, so I'm trying it here.

And there's [a Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/F54H6ZgepEI) with other people experiencing this.